# Rails 4 error when seeding a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a FlavorPizza scaffold and a SizePizza scaffold. I need to set the price of a flavor of a pizza based on it's size (the price of a small pizza is different from a large one). So, I created a PricePizza model, whose migration has :flavor_pizza_id, :size_pizza_id and :price attributes.

I'd like to, when I create/edit a FlavorPizza object, to pass a :price_pizza params, just like that

```
FlavorPizza.create({
    name: 'Muzzarela',
    price_pizzas:[
        {size_pizzas_id: 1, price:'9.99'},
        {size_pizzas_id: 2, price:'12.99}
    ]
})
```

I tried using has many through, but I keep getting errors. undefined method `unscoped`

Here is my code:

price_pizza migration:

```
create_table :price_pizzas do |t|
  t.integer :size_pizzas_id
  t.integer :flavor_pizzas_id

  t.decimal :price, :precision => 5, :scale => 2

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

price_pizza.rb

```
class PricePizza < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flavor_pizzas

    belongs_to :size_pizza
    belongs_to :flavor_pizza
end
```

flavor_pizza.rb

```
class FlavorPizza < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :price_pizzas

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :price_pizzas
end
```

size_pizza.rb

```
class SizePizza < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :price_pizzas
end
```

seeds.rb

```
SizePizza.create([{name: 'Small', diameter: '5.5', pieces: 3}])
FlavorPizza.create([{name: 'Muzzarela', description: 'test description', price_pizzas_attributes: [{size_pizzas_id: 1, price: '9.99'}]}])
#PricePizza.create(size_pizzas_id: 1, flavor_pizzas_id: 1, price: '10')
```

Comment: when, in seeds.rb, i change price_pizzas_attributes to price_pizzas, i get the error: 

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: PricePizza(#49716420) expected, got Hash(#10028260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not directly answer your question, but this is generally how I approach seeds:

```
size = SizePizza.where(name: 'Small').first_or_create(diameter: '5.5', pieces: 3)
flavor = FlavorPizza.where(name: 'Muzzarela').first_or_create(...)
flavor.price_pizzas.create(price: '9.99') # you could also see if the price exists if desired
```

This will prevent you from duplicating data on seeds, accomplish what you're looking to do, and prevent future issues if you add any unique constraints.

Also, for example, if you wanted to create multiple prices, you could always enhance with a loop:

```
%w(9.99 12.99 18.99).each { |price| flavor.price_pizzas.create(price: price) }
```

Comment: I got this error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration

Comment: Your price pizza should belong to flavor pizza, or perhaps the other way. Would need to see how you defined the models in the migrations